# kubectl describe unknown shorthand flag -o

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I think -o is supposed be an universal option for kubectl.
But, somehow I get the following error when I run the following kubectl command.

Can you please tell me why? Thank you.

```
mamun$ kubectl describe secret -n development serviceaccount-foo -o yaml
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'o' in -o
See 'kubectl describe --help' for usage.
```

Comment: `kubectl get` supports the `-o | --output` flag, you can `get` the [`Secrets`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) spec as `yaml`: `kubectl get secret -n development serviceaccount-foo -o yaml`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-o | --output` is not a universal flag, it is not included in the default [`kubectl` flags](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/) (`1.18`) and [`kubectl describe` does not support the `--output` (or shorthand `-o`) flag](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#describe).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
kubectl describe secret -n development serviceaccount-foo -- -o yaml
```